# example of Frobenius endomorphisms that is not automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and $F$ has infinitely many elements. Prove that the map $\sigma: \alpha\mapsto \alpha^p$ is a field endomorphism but not necessarily automorphism. How to prove?

Comment: As it has not been mentioned: the Frobenius is always an automorphism if $F$ is finite. That's why the examples below are all infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is standard, as you will know that $(a + b)^{p} = a^{p} + b^{p}$ in $F$.

Now for an example in which $\sigma$ is not onto, let $K$ be the field with $p$ elements, and consider the field of rational functions $F = K(x)$. Now prove that $x$ is not in the image of $\sigma$.

**Hint**

> Write, by way of contradiction, $$x = \left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{p},$$ with $f(x), g(x) \in K[x]$. You get $f(x)^{p} = x g(x)^{p}$. Compare degrees.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If you've studied finite fields, you should know the ["Freshman's dream theorem,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream_theorem) which should supply some inspiration. This will help you see why the map is additive.

For the example where it is not onto, consider the rational polynomial ring $F_p(x)$, and what taking powers of elements does in this field.

Answer (score 2):

The Frobenius is a homomorphism because of $\sigma(\alpha+\beta)=(\alpha+\beta)^p=\alpha^p+\beta^p=\sigma(\alpha)+\sigma(\beta)$, and $\sigma(\alpha\beta)=(\alpha\beta)^p=\alpha^p\beta^p=\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\beta)$. The kernel of $\sigma$ is an ideal in $F$, hence zero or $F$. Since $\sigma\neq 0$, we have $\ker(\sigma)=0$, and $\sigma$ is injective. But it need not be surjective.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The classical proof that $\sqrt[p]q$ is irrational (via Rational Root Test) extends to the quotient field $K$ of any UFD $R,$ showing that $X^p\! - q$ has no roots in $K$ for prime $q\in R$, e.g. $R = \Bbb Z_p[x]$.